# Targetting Android 1.6 platform from Android 2.1

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have android 2.1 SDK and I am trying to use AndEngine android gaming engine which requires android 1.6. Despite having higher SDK, I can't get AndEngine get to work with bunch of errors I am getting saying particular game example activity has not extended org.android.Activity class.  How can I target Android 1.6 from Android 2.1? I can't even download android 1.6 SDK now.

Comment: Please paste an exact error.  It sounds like a java issue rather then an SDK issue.

Comment: I did not get it, why cant u download the 1.6 SDK ???

Comment: @Nick - I got this message "org.anddev.andengine.examples.launcher.ExampleLauncher does not extend android.app.Activity"

Comment: Sounds to me like a project configuration issue. How did you make AndEngine part of your project?

Comment: @Ted - You were right, this was kind of project configuration issue. I did update and downloaded android 1.6 SDK and was able to clean the project and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did update and downloaded android 1.6 SDK and was able to clean the project and everything worked fine.